# Why is there a WriteConflict in mongoDB when double read and write on different collection?

Tags: spring, mongodb, transactions

I have two requests that are done at the *same time* on my mongodb database.

```
// Request 1:
document1 = READ from collection1
BEGIN Transaction
WRITE document1 to collection1
END Transaction
 
// Request 2:
BEGIN Transaction
document1 = READ from collection1
document2 = READ from collection2
WRITE document2 to collection2
END Transaction
```

Note that the two transactions read from the same collection1 and the same document but write to a different collection.

That gives me a WriteConflict on the Request 1 or 2, 100% of the time.

If I remove the transactions, I get a WriteConflict *sometimes*.

I want to know why I have this WriteConflict ? And after that of course I would want to find a way to avoid it (but I'd like to understand first).

EDIT: I forgot that in my application, we log modification to the db. Therefore what really happens is that both requests write to **another collection**, each inserting a document (using the java library `javers`).

```
// Request 1:
document1 = READ from collection1
BEGIN Transaction
WRITE document1 to collection1
document3 = new Document()
WRITE document3 to collection3
END Transaction

// Request 2:
BEGIN Transaction
document1 = READ from collection1
document2 = READ from collection2
WRITE document2 to collection2
document3 = new Document()
WRITE document3 to collection3
END Transaction
```